# Basic SQL question to Select all results with changes in value

Tags: sql, select

Have a table that's basically the following:

```
ID FileDate Reg# Value
1  01012022 ABC  100.00
2  01012022 CDE   51.20
3  02052022 ABC  101.25
4  02082022 CDE   51.20
```

(Note - the dates noted above will be properly formatted. I'm just using the example above.)

I want to write a query that will return the rows where the VALUE field has changed for any REG# over a given period of time (example, show me all results where the value of a reg has changed between Jan 1 2022 and March 1 2022).

Ideally, the results would show:

01012022 ABC 100.00
02052022 ABC 101.25

Comment: What is the expected result for your sample?

Comment: normally you can use 'between' to select such data but your 'FileDate' does not look like an SQL-Date. You could convert it to a date, for the exact statement we need to know the sql-server you're using (MySQL, Postgres, MSSQL, Oracle, ...).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! Am looking to get the results as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the LAG() function

```
--Declaring and populating a Temp table to store the values you mentioned above [added another two entries to test]
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
ID INT,
FileDate DATE ,
Reg# VARCHAR(3) ,
Value Float)

insert into @tbl (ID, FileDate, Reg#, Value)
values (1, '2022-01-01', 'ABC' , 100) , (2, '2022-01-01', 'CDE' , 51.20), (3, '2022-02-05', 'ABC' , 101.25), (4, '2022-02-08', 'CDE' , 51.20), (5, '2022-03-01', 'ABC' , 101.25), (6, '2022-03-02', 'CDE' , 52);

--Query
with lagtbl as (
SELECT ID, Reg#, FileDate, Value, LAG(t.Value, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Reg# order by Reg#, ID) Lag
from @tbl t)

select lagtbl.ID, lagtbl.Reg#, lagtbl.FileDate, lagtbl.Value
from lagtbl
where Value != Lag
ORDER BY Reg#, ID
```